# Insert list/record field on suitelet form

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Looking to add a  list/record field on a suitelet form. having trouble finding any examples of what this is called, or how to insert this type of field.

Answer (score 3):

When creating the field object, provide a "source" option which specifies the record type.

```
define(['N/ui/serverWidget'], function(serverWidget){

    return { 
        onRequest : function(context){
            var form = serverWidget.createForm({
                title : 'Simple Form'
            });
            var field = form.addField({
                id : 'custpage_customers',
                type : serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
                label : 'Customers',
                source : 'customer' //record type id
            });

            context.response.writePage(form);
        }
    }

});
```

https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4337905245.html